# C++: Returns a local object but doesn't work well

Tags: c++

Didn't use C++ for quite a few  years, this  could be a trivial question:

```
class Slice {
 private:
  size_t n_ = 0;
  const char* data_;

 public:
  Slice() = default;
  Slice(const char* data, size_t n) : data_(data), n_(n) {}

  Slice(const char* s): data_(s), n_(strlen(s)) {}

  Slice(const std::string& s): data_(s.data()), n_(s.size()) {
    // printf("%s %d\n", data_, n_);
  }

  ~Slice() = default;
}



Slice Slice::sub(int start, int len) const {
  assert(start + len < n_);
  auto sub = std::string(this->data_ + start, len);
  Slice s(sub);
  printf("%s\n", sub.data());
  return s;
}
```

I was expecting the `Slice::sub` returns a valid Slice, but it turns out the outside caller can't get the correct value(seems the `sub.data_` was release somehow).

I thought the returned `sub` local object will be copied to the outside variable, right? How do I refine this code?

Comment: It is indeed copied, but you are copying `const char* data_`, a pointer. It is pointing to the data of the temporary object `std::string sub`, so it will be invalid. Probably the easiest way to avoid this is to pass the string by value to the constructor. However, you have a fundamental issue of ownership in your code. You have to decide, do you want the caller to have ownership of the string, or the class to have ownership?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string` throughout your code?  Why are you resorting to `const char *`?  Why isn't the `data_` member a `std::string`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "slice" often refers to a "fat pointer" (pointer + size) which references a chunk of memory without owning it (great for in-situ processing). Asker appears to be making something like `gsl::span` or `std::string_view`. Using `std::string` would defeat the purpose because it would copy the data.

Comment: @iz_ The `ownership` explanation makes a lot sense  to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `const char *` use `char *` or `std::string`.
2. Copy constructor is missing or `std::move` needs to be used.
3. `sub` used for function name and variable name in the same function.